# is it possible to auto start command in mac when command exit

Tags: macos, terminal

I am using `npm run watch` to wath the react typescript project file changes and rebuild the source code, but sometimes the watch process will exit automatically when compile failed, I was wonder is it possible to minitor the npm process in macOS, when the npm run watch command exit, start the command automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an out-of-band monitoring solution; put the command in a loop to run infinitely.

In zsh or bash,

```
while true; do npm run watch; sleep 1; done
```

If `npm run watch` exits, it will sleep 1s, then run the command again.